# Prime Numbers (C++) - Not Working 100%

Tags: c++

I have to code a program that counts how many prime numbers are between 2 and "n".

The first input have to be the total number of tests and other ones have to be the "n" (number limit of the range of numbers to check).

The problem:

My inputs: `7 10 15 50 100 1000 10000 7`

The right outputs for the inputs above: `4 6 15 25 168 1229 4`

What my code outputs: `4 6 15 25 800 9800 4`

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f(int number){
    int m=0,k=1;
    for(k; k<=number; k++)
        if(number%k==0)
            m++;
    if(m==2)
        return true;
}  

    int main (){
    int limit=0, counter=0, test=0;
    bool n;
    cin>>test;
    for(int v=0; v<test; v++){
        cin>>limit;
        for(int i=2; i<=limit; i++){
            n=f(i);
            if (n==true)
                counter++;
        }
        cout<<counter<<endl;
        counter=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to turn on warnings in your compiler. The function f returns a bool (not an int as declared) and does not do so unless the number of divisors of x is equal to two. This are fairly trivial mistakes that any decent C++ compiler should warn you about. Do not ignore warnings.

Comment: Thank You very much, it's 100% working now. I guess im wrong using an online compiler (im using SourceLair). I will start using my dev c++ instead this other one. Thank you for your attetion!